# API V1 - Multicall updates only first digit

Tags: magento-1.7, product, php, inventory

I am trying to update the inventory using multiCall, but it seems that it's only taking the first digit. Here is my php code:

```
$stockItemData = array(
    'sku' => 'somesku-30',
    'qty' => '32'
);

$result = $client->multiCall($sid, array(
     array('product_stock.update', $stockItemData)
));
```

When I look at the product in the control panel, I can only see that the quantity is set to 3. If I try to update with 40, then the control panel shows 4. If I try with 50, it shows 5 only etc..

Any ideas?

Comment: The data is actually taken as-is when looking into the `update()` function in `app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Stock/Item/Api.php`. You can try to debug there and/or in `$product->setStockData($stockData);` to see which data is used here or where it goes wrong.

Comment: Any customization you did on the API or product stock?